# BigQuery: Routine deployment failing with error "Unknown option: description"

Tags: google-bigquery

We use terraform to deploy BigQuery objects (datasets, tables, routines etc..) to region europe-west2 in GCP. We do this many many times a day and all of a sudden at "2021-08-18T21:15:44.033910202Z" our deployments starting failing when attempting to deploy BigQuery routines. They are all failing with errors of the form:

```json
status: {
  code: 3
  message: "Unknown option: description"
}
```

[image]

Here is the first log message I can find pertaining to this error (I have redacted project names):

```
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 3,
      "message": "Unknown option: description"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "deployer-dev@myadminproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "serviceAccountDelegationInfo": [
        {
          "firstPartyPrincipal": {
            "principalEmail": "deployer-dev@myadminproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "10.51.0.116",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "Terraform/0.14.7 (+https://www.terraform.io) Terraform-Plugin-SDK/2.5.0 terraform-provider-google/3.69.0,gzip(gfe)",
      "callerNetwork": "//compute.googleapis.com/projects/myadminproject/global/networks/__unknown__",
      "requestAttributes": {},
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "bigquery.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.RoutineService.InsertRoutine",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "projects/myproject/datasets/p00003818_dp_model",
        "permission": "bigquery.routines.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/myproject/datasets/p00003818_dp_model/routines/UserProfile_Events_AllCarData_Deployment",
    "metadata": {
      "routineCreation": {
        "routine": {
          "routineName": "projects/myproject/datasets/p00003818_dp_model/routines/UserProfile_Events_AllCarData_Deployment"
        },
        "reason": "ROUTINE_INSERT_REQUEST"
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "ak27xdbke",
  "resource": {
    "type": "bigquery_dataset",
    "labels": {
      "dataset_id": "p00003818_dp_model",
      "project_id": "myproject"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-08-18T21:15:43.109609Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/myproject/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-08-18T21:15:44.033910202Z"
}
```

The fact that this occurred without any changes by ourselves indicates that this is a problem at the Google end. I also observe that whilst we witnessed this in a few projects it occurred first in one project and then a few minutes later in another - that may or may not be helpful information.

Posting here in case anyone else hits this problem and also hoping it might catch the attention of a googler.

---

UPDATE! I have reproduced the pproblem using the REST API https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/routines/insert

I have entered a payload that *does not* include a description and that successfully creates a routine:

[image: successful rest call screenshot]

However, if I include a description which, as this screenshot indicates, is a valid parameter:
[image]

then the request fails:

[image]

Comment: Happy to confirm that simply removing descriptions from our google_bigquery_routine terraform resources solves the problem so this is now a minor irritant rather than a blocker. Google should be made aware though.

Comment: Was about to write exactly the same post as yours : we face the exact same issue, and I came to the same conclusion. Hopefully someone at Google's read this...

Comment: Yep. I’ve had acknowledgement from Google Support that they have reproduced the problem and they’ve escalated to <whoever these things get escalated to>.